# Executing query through pymysql not returning the same results as running in MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm new to Python and PyMySQL, so I may have something misconfigured.

I'm connecting to MySQL without any problems. I tested it doing a **SELECT** and a **DESC** on a table, and was able to view the results.

I now have a query that I substitute date parameters into and want returned the count of a column (customers) and the total number of customers multiplied times a value.

The count of customers comes back correctly, but the product calculation returns **None**. Before executing the query, I print it to the console and copy that to MySQLWorkbench to run, and the correct values are returned.

In my *main* module I connect to the DB and get a cursor. I then get date values to use in the query and call the function that executes the query.

```
connection = dbConnection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
startDate = input("enter start date (yyyy-mm-dd): ").strip()
endDate = input("enter end date (yyyy-mm-dd): ").strip()
my_queries.queryTotals(cursor, startDate, endDate)
connection.close()
```

In my *my_queries* module I have the query and substitute the entered dates into the query string, then execute the query and fetch the results:

```
totalsSQL = '''select
@total:=count(cus.customer_id) as customers, format(@total * 1.99, 2) as total
from customer cus
join membership mem on mem.membership_id=cus.current_membership_id
where mem.request='START'
and (mem.purchase_date > (unix_timestamp(date('{}'))*1000)  and mem.purchase_date < unix_timestamp(date('{}'))*1000);'''

formattedSQL = totalsSQL.format(startDate, endDate)

cursor.execute(formattedSQL)
result = cursor.fetchone()
```

I get a result of (32, None) as opposed to getting a numeric value for the 2nd column value.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a variable for an aggregate function, and refer to it later in the same `SELECT` list. Aggregates don't get their values until all the rows have been selected, but other columns are calculated while selecting rows.

Just use `COUNT(*)` in both places.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS customers, FORMAT(COUNT(*) * 1.99, 2) AS total
join membership mem on mem.membership_id=cus.current_membership_id
where mem.request='START'
and (mem.purchase_date > (unix_timestamp(date('{}'))*1000) 
and mem.purchase_date < unix_timestamp(date('{}'))*1000)
```

Also, to prevent SQL injection you should use a parametrized query instead of substituting variables with `format()`.

```
totalsSQL = '''
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS customers, FORMAT(COUNT(*) * 1.99, 2) AS total
    join membership mem on mem.membership_id=cus.current_membership_id
    where mem.request='START'
    and (mem.purchase_date > (unix_timestamp(date(%s))*1000) 
    and mem.purchase_date < unix_timestamp(date(%s))*1000)
'''
cursor.execute(totalsSQL, (startDate, endDate))
```

Comment: That did it! I'll change the string substitution, too.

What was throwing me off is that it does work with the workbench. Must have been a timing fluke. Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't know why it worked with workbench. I just tried it with the CLI interface and it didn't work.

Comment: don't forget that variables persist between queries. So if you try the query twice, the second one will use the count from the first.

Comment: That was probably it. Learn something new every day!